# Getting started with RGoogleAnalytics

Tags: r

I've run the following code (according to http://online-behavior.com/analytics/r ) but get the error

```
 Error in QueryBuilder() : 
     argument "query.params.list" is missing, with no default
```

All packages installed successfully, and a googling the error did not produce helpful advice. Any pointers? Thanks.

```
 # run <sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev> beforehand
 rm(list=ls())
 setwd('~')
 install.packages(c("RCurl", "httr" , "rjson" , "RGoogleAnalytics", "ggplot2","plyr", 
               "gridExtra", "reshape" , "RColorBrewer"))

 require("RCurl")
 require("rjson")
 require("ggplot2")
 require("plyr")
 require("gridExtra")
 require("reshape")
 require("RGoogleAnalytics")

 query <- QueryBuilder()
 access_token <- query$authorize()
```

Comment: It appears that guide is out of date. Look at the demos provided with the package itself `demo(package="RGoogleAnalytics")` or look at the [github repository](https://github.com/Tatvic/RGoogleAnalytics/blob/master/demo/data_extraction_demo.R)